# Selecting multiple column headers and then deleting those columns

Tags: excel, vba

***PLEASE EXCUSE ANY MISTAKES FOR NOT FOLLOWING PROPER POSTING FORMAT. THIS IS MY FIRST POSTING***

I have a headings in `row 1`. I want to select multiple column headings and then delete those columns. I also want the code to not break if a certain heading specified doesn't exist (i.e. if a heading that it is searching for doesn't exist, the loop continues).

I've got code that works to find a specified heading and delete that column. However, I don't want to do this code for each heading to delete (roughly 20 headings). I also don't know how to make it so that it doesn't break if a heading doesn't exist. This will be something that I do on a monthly basis and most likely all the headings will always be the same, but I can't guarantee that. I downloaded a `.cs`v file and work with that.

The `MsgBox` in my code is from an example I found online. I don't actually want a message box if it doesn't find a heading. I just want it to skip over a heading it doesn't find and continue searching for the other ones.

```
Find a column header and delete that column
    Dim rngHeadings As Range
    Set rngHeadings = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Find("Category")
        If rngHeadings Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Can't find that"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        rngHeadings.EntireColumn.Select
        Selection.Delete
```

So "`Category`" is one of the headings. Some others are "`AirDur`", "`RefNbr`", etc. (I can fill in the rest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim rngHeadings As Range, f As Range
Set rngHeadings = ActiveSheet.Rows(1)

For Each h in Array("Category","AirDur")
    Set f = rngHeadings.Find(What:=h, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then f.EntireColumn.delete
Next h
```

Comment: Thanks for that code. It worked perfectly. One question. Is there a way that I can do the opposite. Specify which columns I DON'T want to delete based on a certain heading, then delete the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try at answering this, please see coments for details.

```vb
Sub delColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'better use Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetName") / or ActiveWorkbook / or specific workbook
Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Get the last column
Dim R As Long, C As Long

Dim arrHeadingsToDelete() As String
arrHeadingsToDelete = Split("Category,AirDur,RefNbr", ",")              'Add more as needed

For C = lCol To 1 Step -1                                               'Loop from last column to first
    For R = LBound(arrHeadingsToDelete) To UBound(arrHeadingsToDelete)  'Loop through each of the headings in the above array
        If ws.Cells(1, C) = arrHeadingsToDelete(R) Then                 'If there is a match
            ws.Cells(1, C).EntireColumn.Delete                          'Delete the column...
            Exit For                                                    '...and move to check the next one
        End If
    Next R
Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the one above is much simpler. And as a beginner, I need simple right now.